# filtration of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a vector bundle on a variety. When is it true that my vector bundle admits a filtration with subquotients all line bundles? (I am most interested in the case of an integral projective curve.)

Comment: In your case it is always true. In general of course it is not, like the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Here is a sketch (and this is often attributed to Serre). Let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank greater than one over a projective curve $X$, and as usual denote by $E(n)$, twisting by an ample bundle. Then, for large $n$ $E(n)$ is globally generated. Now, using the fact that rank $E$ is larger than dimension of $X$, a general section of $E(n)$ will be nowhere vanishing. That is, we have an exact sequence, $$0\to \mathcal{O}_X\to E(n)\to G\to 0$$, with $G$ a vector bundle.Iinduction on rank.